# codeigniter multiple applications, remove directory using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

First and foremost, I have setup my CI installation for multiple apps. Here's my directory structure.

```
application/
   - cache/
   - config/
   - controllers/
         - admin/
              - admin.php
         - site1/
              - site1.php
         - site2/
              - site2.php
         - default.php
   - core/
   - errors/
system
index.php
```

Now that I have uploaded it on my web hosting and assigned it on the domain, I now have this as my URL for each of my sites.

http://example.com/admin

http://example.com/site1

http://example.com/site2

With the said setup, I only want http://example.com to access admin and site1. By going directly to http://example.com, it will redirect me to the site1 controller but without the directory "site1". So it will have a url of "http://example.com" only. Adding "/admin" will redirect to the admin controller.

Same goes for other controllers. I will assign site2 to http://anothersite.com. Only having the said URL without the directory "/site2". And adding a "/admin" will redirect to the admin controller.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have some issues with this approach.

Try this one, the HMVC style
[Modular Extensions HMVC](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc)

Comment: Thanks! Now that I have this structure, my url still shows up the same. How could I set a domain to specifically load a controller?
Lets take this an example: www.site1.com will load the site1 controller and www.site2.com will load the site2 controller without the site1 or site2 directory being shown after the hostname (www.site1.com/site1 or www.site2.com/site2) but both can have access to the admin controller (www.site1.com/admin or www.site2.com/admin is okay).